# Transitive matrix from base B to base A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am brushing up on linear algebra, and I came across this question:

**Find the transitive matrix from B to A for the following bases in $\Bbb{R}^3$. B = {(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)} and A = {(1, 0, 1), (0, -1, 2), (2, 3, -5)}.**

This was very similar to another piece of text I had read earlier: Suppose T: V->W is a transformation that rotates every vector by the angle $\theta$. Here V = W = $\Bbb{R}^2$. Find A.

The solution the text provided went something like this: Apply T.

(1, 0)->(cos$\theta$, sin$\theta$) = cos$\theta$ x (1, 0) + sin$\theta$ x (0, 1)

(0, 1)-> (-sin$\theta$, cos$\theta$) = -sin$\theta$ x (1, 0) + cos$\theta$ x (0, 1)

So T is

| cos$\theta$ -sin$\theta$ |

| sin$\theta$ cos$\theta$ |

Now why can't I say since (1, 0, 1) = 1 x (1, 0, 0) + 0 x (0, 1, 0) + 1 x (0, 0, 1)

(0, -1, 2) = 0 x (1, 0, 0) + -1 x (0, 1, 0) + 2 x (0, 0, 1)

(2, 3, -5) = 2 x (1, 0, 0) + 3 x (0, 1, 0) + 5 x (0, 0, 1)

The transitive matrix is

|1 0  2 |

|0 -1 3 |

|1 2 -5 | ?

**I know the correct answer is the inverse of the matrix above, but I would like to know why my reasoning is wrong.**

Answer (score 1):

The matrix you have is one that takes the vectors of basis $B$ and yields the vectors in basis $A$. What you need is the opposite: a matrix that takes each vector in $A$ and gives you a vector in $B$.

So, if $a,b,c$ are the entries of the first column of your matrix, we should have
$$
a(1, 0, 1)+b(0, -1, 2)+c(2, 3, -5)=(1,0,0)
$$